# Express: is it possible to bypass sessions for static files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using a quite straightforward setup of Express + Mongoose + Passport + Connect-mongo, and everything works fine. The only thing that is puzzling me, is that I can see the `passport.unserializeUser` called even for static files, which is - from my application point of view - absolutely pointless.

I can understand that there are cases where you want the static files to be served under some sort of authorization as well, but I wonder how I could "skip" the whole session middleware in case I'm serving a static file.

(In a production environment I could not use cookies for assets)

Comment: just put `express.static` above all the other middleware

Comment: It works, and I found it fantastic. Jonathan, would you mind "answering" the question so I can actually give you some karma? :)

Comment: i don't do this for the points!

Comment: Yeah, but this place is for people to find answers. Do you you mind if I answer myself with your hints?

Comment: nope. a full explanation and/or example would be better as an answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Middleware is called upon in the order it was added. Just move the static middleware to be very early in your `app.js`.

For example:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
// any other middleware
app.use(passport()); // or whatever your passport config looks like
```

Answer (score 1):

You could serve the static files from another domain which does not store any cookies at all. That also means that you cannot do any (security) checks before serving those files.

This technique is used by various sites, such as StackOverflow, Facebook and LinkedIn.

Comment: Yes, of course, and I know (as my last sentence states). But I wonder if I can do it programmatically :)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Node.js + Express + Passport, but you might be able to set up your web server to return the requested file if it exists and redirect to your application if the request is not an existing file or folder.