# How to serve static files without creating new sessions (Or enable sessions per Route/Polices only)

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm using the native express in a middleware to serve my static application, the problem is that i'm saving my sessions in MongoDB, and for each request, one new session is created. Any idea how to solve this? Is there a way to use sessions only on a route? Because i'm only using sessions in the manager(with passport). Disable sessions in a static folder should solve my problem too. Thank you.

```
Config/http.js    
var express = require('express');

module.exports.http = {

  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    app.use('/', express.static(process.cwd() + '/assets/site'));
  },

  middleware: {

    passportInit    : require('passport').initialize(),
    passportSession : require('passport').session(),

    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'customMiddleware',
      'session',
      'passportInit',
      'passportSession',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call first your static middleware and then session middleware ,
[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791136/express-is-it-possible-to-bypass-sessions-for-static-files?rq=1%20Posible%20duplicate)

Comment: I tryed change the order: [ 'startRequestTimer', 'cookieParser', 'customMiddleware', 'session', 'passportInit', 'passportSession',....But That did not work with sails. Maybe in native express. I call my middleware before the sessions and passport, also they are not going through any police.